# Using xml.etree.ElementTree.find() with custom tags

Tags: python, xml, elementtree, yahoo-weather-api, temboo

I am using Temboo to get the weather for an address on Yahoo. Since this returns XML code, I am using `ElementTree.find()` to find the custom Yahoo tag `<yweather:condition/>`. But when I run the program, I get the following error:

```
SyntaxError: prefix 'yweather' not found in prefix map
```

How do I use a custom XML tag with `ElementTree.find()`?

Comment: The "prefix" is called namespace. Take a look at xml.etree.ElementTree.register_namespace()

Comment: @Hai Vu I am not very knowledgeable about XML. Thank you for the input but is there a similar function that is implemented in Python 2.7?

Comment: Yes, see: https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html